# i am trying to add a month to a date in php, the date is picked via datepicker YYY-MM-DD format

Tags: php

I am trying to add months to a date

```
for ($i=0;$i<$months;$i++)
{
    $newdate = strtotime ( "+1 month", strtotime ( $date ) );
    $newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );
}
```

how to get the $i inside the function?

Comment: What does `$date` look like?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you have a for-loop? Also, you're overwriting the `$newdate` variable on each iteration so after the loop, it will only contain the last value (which, in all fairness, would be the same as as in all the other iterations). If the question is how to add `$i` number of months, then do: `"+{$i} month"`

Comment: $date variable will have date as 2018-10-30, i need to add 12 months iteratively to get the other dates for the 12 month period.

Comment: What do you want as the result for February?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is one possible solution

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$months;$i++)
{
    $newdate = strtotime ( "+".$i." month", strtotime ( $date ) );
    $newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );
}
```